# Using kotlin method with value class in signature from Java code

Tags: java, kotlin, interface, value-class

I have such Kotlin entity

```
value class EntityId(val id: Long) {}
```

and some service's interface

```
interface Service {
    fun do(entityId: EntityId)
}
```

and its implementation.

But when I use the interface from **Java** code like this

```
{
    ...
    EntityId id = new EntityId(1L);
    service.do(id) // service is interface here 
}
```

I receive the compilation error. But it's pretty understandable behaviour because Kotlin compiler generates `fun do(entityId: Long)` from the sources.
Okay, let use something like this `service.do(1L)`.
Another issue will occur:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method do(long)
```

I guess it occurs because interface actually isn't changed during compilation. I found a single way - replace `value class` with `data class` but I would have `value class`.

Maybe, does some workaround exist for such a case?

Comment: The Kotlin compiler deliberately makes this hard to allow future versions to compile things differently, e.g. when Java gets Project Valhalla and doesn't need this workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could overload the function that takes `value class` with a function that takes `Long` and calls the original under the hood.

Kotlin

```
@JvmInline
value class EntityId(val id: Long)

interface Service {
    fun process(entityId: EntityId)
    fun process(entityId: Long)
}

class ServiceImpl : Service {
    override fun process(entityId: EntityId) {
    }

    override fun process(entityId: Long) {
        process(EntityId(entityId))
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from Java with a `Long` literal:

```
Service service = new ServiceImpl();
service.process(42L);
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work for me because my `Service` is an interface, and `ServiceImpl` contains method `override fun do(...)`. But overridden methods can't be marked with `@JvmName` annotation.

Comment: In this case you don't need `@JvmName`, you can just add a new method to the interface, answer updated. @ArturShaikhutdinov